Always run a play in particular host, with --limit option
$ cat inventory
[dbservers]
DB1 ansible_host=10.252.22.163

[webservers]
WS1 ansible_host=10.252.22.163

[common]
CS1 ansible_host=10.252.22.163

$ cat pb.yml
- name: db and web 
  hosts:
    - dbservers
    - webservers 
  tasks:
    - name: Run task
      debug:
        msg: 'Running on all dbservers and webserver'

$ cat common.yml
- name: common task should run on common host only(that too only once)
  hosts:
    - common 
  tasks:
    - name: Run common task
      debug:
        msg: 'Running common task'

$ cat install.yml
- import_playbook: "pb.yml"

- import_playbook: "common.yml"

Is it possible to run common play (only once) on CS1 host, every time any of below commands are run?
> ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml --limit 'DB1'
> ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml --limit 'WS1'


use --limit DB1;CS1 and --limit WS1;CS1. Hosts out of the limit are never addressed in the play loop.

On every install(DB1/WS1), I have a play that I want to run once implicitly on a particular host, without user specifying it.

One way could be to make all tasks of common.yml delegate_to: CS1 + run_once: true

looks like delegate_to is only for tasks, i am unable to delegate entire common.yml play

@Arjun you can put all the tasks of the common play into a block and set delegate_to to this block.

This would require some changes to your common.yml:

in order to be able to delegate the task(s) to the host that's not included into the --limit, the play should be targeted to a parent group, i.e. all;
since you can't delegate the whole play, you can group all its tasks into a block instead and use delegate_to: CS1 on that block;
you will also need to use run_once: true as otherwise Ansible would run the play on all the available hosts:

# common.yml
---
- name: common task should run on common host only (that too only once)
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: A block that would delegate all its tasks to the common host
      delegate_to: CS1
      run_once: true
      block:
        - name: Run common task
          debug:
            msg: 'Running common task'

This would give the result like below:
ansible-playbook install.yml --inventory inventory.ini --limit DB1

PLAY [db and web]
TASK [Run task]
ok: [DB1] => 
  msg: Running on all dbservers and webserver)

PLAY [common task should run on common host only (that too only once)] 
TASK [Run common task]
ok: [DB1 -> CS1(10.252.22.163)] => 
  msg: Running common task

PLAY RECAP
DB1: ok=2   changed=0   unreachable=0   failed=0   skipped=0   rescued=0   ignored=0


this is one posible solution:
inventory
[dbservers]
DB1 ansible_host=10.252.22.163

[webservers]
WS1 ansible_host=10.252.22.163

[common]
CS1 ansible_host=10.252.22.163

install.yml
---
- name: Common tasks
  hosts: common
  tasks:
    - name: Include common tasks
      include_tasks: common.yml

- name: tasks
  hosts: "{{ target_group }}"
  tasks:
    - name: task 1 
      command: echo "hello"

common.yml
- name: Run common task COMMON
  debug:
    msg: 'Running common task'

run commands
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml -e target_group=dbservers
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml -e target_group=webservers

